# How to add new pages existing django app through admin page?

Tags: django

I have an existing Django app. What is the best way to add new pages to it through the admin page, without actually coding every time. I want to add static pages, with URLs through the admin page.

- Add new page with new URLs
- Add through admin page, not through coding every time. One time code to handle this.
  Is there a way out?

Comment: Please go through any tutorial implementing a blog app. That's what you are looking for.

Comment: Take a look at this

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/flatpages/